# Delete all rows that has nth column element == 1

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a 2D numpy matrix that looks something like this

```
[
 [10, 20, 30, 8, 1],
 [25, 60, 10, 1, 2],
 [54, 12, 89, 5, 1],
 [44, 53, 34, 1, 3]
]
```

I need to remove all rows that has the 4th element (4th column) == 1. In this case, I would need to remove the 2nd and 4th rows. 
Other than running a loop through the matrix and checks the 4th element in each row, is there a quick syntax in Python that allows me to do this?

Comment: `result = arr[arr[:, -1] != 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing elements you can select the rows that meet your condition.

```
arr[arr[:,3] != 1]
```

Example:

```
>>> arr[arr[:,3] != 1]
array([[10, 20, 30,  8,  1],
       [54, 12, 89,  5,  1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```py
temp = [
 [10, 20, 30, 8, 1],
 [25, 60, 10, 1, 2],
 [54, 12, 89, 5, 1],
 [44, 53, 34, 1, 3]
]

temp = np.array(temp)
arg = np.argwhere(temp[:,3]!=1)
temp[arg[:,0]]
```

You will get the result:

```
array([[10, 20, 30,  8,  1],
       [54, 12, 89,  5,  1]])
```

Comment: The solution posted by @abc is definitely cleaner and better than mine. Since `numpy.argwhere` is kinda slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension.

Demo:

```
arr = [
 [10, 20, 30, 8, 1],
 [25, 60, 10, 1, 2],
 [54, 12, 89, 5, 1],
 [44, 53, 34, 1, 3]
]
new_arr = [l for l in arr if l[3] != 1]

print(new_arr)
[[10, 20, 30, 8, 1], [54, 12, 89, 5, 1]]
```

Comment: You are still using a python loop to permute the numpy array row by row, which is not desired.